# failing to connect to spark driver when submitting job to spark in yarn mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I submit a spark job to the cluster it failed with the following exeption in the shell:

```
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
> Application application_1497125798633_0065 finished with failed status
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1244)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1290)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:750)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 17/06/29 10:25:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

This is what it gives in Yarn logs:

```
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /0.0.0.0:35994 at
> org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
> at
> org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
> at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194) at
> org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190) at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Which I guess means it failed to connect to the driver. I tried to increase "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" parameter but that didn't work.

This is the submit command I use:

```
/bin/spark-submit \
  --class example.Hello \
  --jars ... \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024 ...(jar file path)
```

I am using HDP-2.6.1.0 and spark 2.1.1

Comment: Can you remove `--supervise` and start over? Can you paste the entire output from `spark-shell`? Can you paste the logs from YARN? Use [yarn logs -applicationId](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#logs).

Comment: I removed it from the command and nothing changed. I updated my question to have the shell error as well as the exception in yarn logs

Comment: Can you paste the other lines above the exception? I think I've seen a similar exception and it was at shutdown. Show more logs. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for replying @JacekLaskowski but I found the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Spark in Yarn mode (which what I was doing) is the right to use spark in HDP as stated here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/52591/standalone-spark-using-ambari.html

which means I should not specify a master or use the start-master / start-slave commands.

The problem was that the driver IP was taken as 0.0.0.0 for some reason and all the cluster nodes were trying to contact the driver using the local interface and thus fail.
I fixed this by setting the following configuration in conf/spark-defaults.conf:

> spark.driver.port=20002
>
> spark.driver.host=HOST_NAME

and by changing the deploy-mode to client to make it deply the driver locally.

Comment: I was having the same issue on Spark 2.3.1 This solution worked in my case, ie adding spark.driver.host property in the conf/spark-defaults.conf

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /0.0.0.0:35994
```

Try `spark-submit --master <master-ip>:<spark-port>` to submit the job.

Comment: I tried that and I got this exception:
` 17/06/29 23:35:30 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /127.0.0.1:6
066 is closed
17/06/29 23:35:30 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 127.0.0.1:6066
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from /127.0.0.1:6066 closed`
this is what I got from the master log:
`WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer`